# exception handling with the facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, exception, facebook-php-sdk

I have noticed that when uploading images to facebook album via created by my app using the php sdk for facebook, the sdk will occasionally throw an error.

I got an error from the sdk a few times in testing...  however I put in a try catch...

```
    try{
        $picID = $this->facebook->api('/'.$this->aid.'/photos','post',$photo_details);
        var_dump($picID);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo('exception caught '.var_dump($e));
    }
```

and am trying to test it but by dumb luck the error will not occur again.  Can someone tell me if I can catch an exception this way?

Thanks.

Comment: exception was not caught by this...  I still got the following
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught CurlException: 55: SSL connection send timeout
  thrown in <b>/blah blah blah/base_facebook.php</b> on line <b>910</b><br />

anyone tell me how to properly catch this so I can retry?

Comment: I am talking to myself here.  it seems the exception IS caught by this technique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
try {
    $picID = $this->facebook->api('/'.$this->aid.'/photos','post',$photo_details);
} catch(CurlException $e) {
    echo('exception caught '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I accepted the answer because it added greater depth to my solution.  I have already coded with Exception now tho.  Thank you for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 2):

Don't really want to ressurect a question from 2012 but this has changed since then for anyone looking into it now. For modern code using Facebook SDK 5.x.x use the code...

```
try {
    //Do something with the facebook code here
catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
    //Handle the exception here
    //This will only catch exceptions thrown by the SDK but will cover them all, even ones thrown by libraries called by the SDK.
}
```